# SKScene crashing the app while closing the view controller

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I am following tutorial to float hearts like Periscope.

[Link to Tutorial](https://github.com/itsarjun/HeartAnimation)

To give basic hint, I am posting the code below

```
let heartHeight: CGFloat = 18.0

let heartsFile = "heart-bubbles.sks"

class HeartBubblesScene : SKScene {
var emitter: SKEmitterNode?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scaleMode = .ResizeFill // make scene's size == view's size
    //backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

func beginBubbling() {

    emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: heartsFile)

    let x = floor(size.width / 2.0)
    let y = heartHeight

    emitter!.position = CGPointMake(x, y)

    emitter!.name = "heart-bubbles"
    emitter!.targetNode = self

    emitter?.numParticlesToEmit = 1

    addChild(emitter!)

    emitter?.resetSimulation()
}
```

In my viewdidload, I have code like this to present the scene

```
    heartBubblesView.presentScene(heartBubblesScene)
```

Where heartBubblesView is a SKView, which I made through an Outlet.

The issue arises when I to and fro to that view controller; suddenly, it crashed and shows me below logical:

> SpriteKit`std::__1::__tree_iterator*, int> std::__1::__tree, std::__1::allocator >::find:
>       0x29fd0f4c <+0>:  ldr    r3, [r0, #4]!
>       0x29fd0f50 <+4>:  cbz    r3, 0x29fd0f82            ; <+54>
>       0x29fd0f52 <+6>:  ldr.w  r12, [r1]
>       0x29fd0f56 <+10>: mov    r9, r0
>   ->  0x29fd0f58 <+12>: ldr    r2, [r3, #0x10]
>       0x29fd0f5a <+14>: cmp    r2, r12
>       0x29fd0f5c <+16>: bhs    0x29fd0f66                ; <+26>
>       0x29fd0f5e <+18>: ldr    r3, [r3, #0x4]
>       0x29fd0f60 <+20>: cmp    r3, #0x0
>       0x29fd0f62 <+22>: bne    0x29fd0f58                ; <+12>
>       0x29fd0f64 <+24>: b      0x29fd0f70                ; <+36>
>       0x29fd0f66 <+26>: ldr    r2, [r3]
>       0x29fd0f68 <+28>: mov    r9, r3
>       0x29fd0f6a <+30>: cmp    r2, #0x0
>       0x29fd0f6c <+32>: mov    r3, r2
>       0x29fd0f6e <+34>: bne    0x29fd0f58                ; <+12>
>       0x29fd0f70 <+36>: cmp    r9, r0
>       0x29fd0f72 <+38>: beq    0x29fd0f82                ; <+54>
>       0x29fd0f74 <+40>: ldr.w  r2, [r9, #0x10]
>       0x29fd0f78 <+44>: ldr    r1, [r1]
>       0x29fd0f7a <+46>: cmp    r1, r2
>       0x29fd0f7c <+48>: it     lo
>       0x29fd0f7e <+50>: movlo  r9, r0
>       0x29fd0f80 <+52>: b      0x29fd0f84                ; <+56>
>       0x29fd0f82 <+54>: mov    r9, r0
>       0x29fd0f84 <+56>: mov    r0, r9
>       0x29fd0f86 <+58>: bx     lr

Then I tried to add the deinit to above class

```
deinit
{
    emitter?.targetNode = nil
    emitter!.removeAllChildren()

}
```

That does not work either.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know but I put this below deinitialser method in my view controller with removing all children of that SKScene seems to resolve the issue.

```
  deinit
{
   heartBubblesScene.removeAllChildren()
}
```